# Use Selenium Webdriver to capture all the values from Google Auto Suggest Edit Box and display them in the console

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class AutoSuggestEditBox {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=w3s7U6DQJsSJ8QfDloEg");

         driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("cognizant i");

        List<WebElement> lst=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_e']/table/tbody/tr"));
         for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
            System.out.println(lst.get(i).getText());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please guys help me to solve this program using webdriver in java language i dont find the exact solution to get all the autosuggest editbox list in a console

Comment: What is the result from your code? It helps to have a bit more context than just the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> lst=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".gssb_e > .gssb_m > tbody > tr"));
     for(int i=1;i<=lst.size();i++){
 By selector = By.cssSelector(".gssb_e > .gssb_m > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(i) > td > div > table  > tbody  > tr > td:nth-of-type(1) > span");
WebElement el = driver.findElement(selector);
        System.out.println(el.getText());
    }

}
```

I think this should work I haven't tried it. But that should print all auto suggests from google

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.gLFyf.gsfi")).sendKeys("selenium");
List<WebElement> suggestions=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul>li.sbct"));
System.out.println(suggestions.size());
            for(int i=0;i<suggestions.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i+" "+suggestions.get(i).getText());
            }
```